# What form should i use making a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, database

I'm kinda lost and need some help.
In the past i have used php and mysql to make websites that are data driven with database. Now i want to use my C# skills to make a site. This new site will be connected to database and have alot of data.

Should i use Visual Studio to do a ASP.NET site ?
What is this WPF Browser Application thing, does that work in all browsers ?
Is there something else that i could use c# with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As new to .Net, To start with webappication Following Combination might help

If want robust Development

- Asp.Net WebForms (Engine)
- ADO.NET (Data Access)
- SQL SERVER (DB)

Above will do most of the code for you and you can easily alter the disigner or modify accordingly.

If you want more control over your Development process, I would recommend following

- ASP.NET MVC (Engine)
- LinqToSQL, NHibernate (DataAccess)
- SQL SERVER (DB)

WPF is next generation of Windows / desktop based application programmng not Web based. It does provide a template for Browser based Application but is probably limited to Internet Explorer, but not all browsers. I not sure about WPF, some one might add to it.
As you intend to work on Web Application, this would not be a good idea to start with

IDE fro all above is definitely Visual Studio 2008+, as it provides access to all of the units / components of your application including view and designer for Database.
You can download one here

[**for 3 Months Trial**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700831.aspx)

Hope it help

Comment: I think i will check out the first one, at least for now. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4):

When using C#, the best development environment is indeed Visual Studio. It is not the only option, with [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) and [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) being two other IDEs that are themselves written in C# and have integrated build and debugging facilities.

In terms of what technology to use for building a website, you can use [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/), but I think that for someone with PHP experience, [ASP MVC](http://www.asp.net/(S(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc/) will be more natural.

The WPF browser application will require quite a lot of learning (WPF, XAML and more) and will be an IE only proposition.

Comment: Am i missing something by using other IDEs then visual studio ? Like the datagrid system, better or worse ?
What do you use ?

Comment: I use Visual Studio. It integrates a good debugger, great editor, development web server, source control and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) page:

> XAML browser applications (XBAPs) combines features of both Web applications and rich-client applications. Like Web applications, XBAPs can be published to a Web server and launched from Internet Explorer. Like rich-client applications, XBAPs can take advantage of the capabilities of WPF. Developing XBAPs is also similar to rich-client development. This topic provides a simple, high-level introduction to XBAP development and underscores where XBAP development is different than standard rich-client development.

If you want to make an application similar to what you've done in PHP ASP.NET is your answer.

Comment: thanks for the answears guys, could you recommend some tutorial for asp.net ? Something that shows how to use database connections if its like in WPF.
Also, does ASP.NET support XML editing like WPF ? Got so used to that :)

Comment: Some video tutorials on ASP.NET can be found at: http://www.asp.net/learn

Answer (score 0):

I would say to start with APS.Net and then move on to WPF, silverlight as Oded mentioned

> The WPF browser application will require quite a lot of learning (WPF, XAML and more) and will be an IE only proposition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well it works since I use PHP, but Expression Web has  ASP.NET support including GUI widgets.